# Whats causing this garbled text below my pages?

Tags: users

Hoping someone might have experienced this and know the culprit code. This keeps appearing below some pages intermittently. Only on logged in members. 
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. I'm afraid it will not be possible to debug your site from here. Also, you pasted problematic text as image. This means future readers will not find it (as it's not searchable), and your question is totally useless for them.

Comment: If you change to a default Drupal theme, does this still happen? If not, then It might be a template file on your theme that is causing this. So look at all the files in your theme's template folder (.tpl.php files) and the template.php file.

Comment: This is a dup.  The problem is more than likely having page compression on in Drupal, and also enabled in Apache.  Would need to dig for the target question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try searching for part of the string in your codebase.  If you have SSH access then you could run something like:

```
cd /path/to/document/root
grep -r "W!b\EU6" .
```

Otherwise if the file is on you local computer then you could use any search tool to look for "W!b\EU6" (those particular characters are from the last line of your screenshot.

Note that it may not be in the codebase.  It could be in the database or could be the output of some function such as an encoding function.  You could check if it's in the database by dumping the database to a .sql file (not compressed) and searching in that.

If you find it and are not sure what to do with the results then paste them here for further advice.